# Informing user of ongoing async operation

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap, from what I can see it has a very extensive list of components:

[Bootstrap components](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/)

I need to provide feedback for an ongoing async operation. I'm sending some form data to the server and would like to visually inform the user in the meantime that the operation is taking place, once completed, I'd like to inform that is has completed succesfully or an error has ocurred.

There is so many ways of doing this and before implmenting it myself, does bootstrap offer possible solutions for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to implement it yourself,
I suggest you use Bootstrap's Modal for confirmation dialogs.
You could checkout this tiny tutorial about how to make a spinner yourself here:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp
and this tutorial about notifications using bootstrap: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-alerts.php